# keyboard not disappear when used resignFirstResponder in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

coding environment sierra 10.12，Xcode 8.1. Two textField in my roorView, if   first textfield's text is nil, second textfield will can't  be editing.When i used resignFirstResponder method to turn off keyboard in textFieldDidBeginEditing: method, keyboard not disappear. I add a fullscreen TapGesture in rootView. I'm very confused，anyone have ideas to help me deal with this problem?

`

```
  #pragma mark -- UITextFieldDelegate
        - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
            if (textField == self.password) {
                [self.username resignFirstResponder];
                NSString *name = self.username.text;
                if ([name isEqualToString:@""]) {
                    [CFBlurHUD showFaild:@"sign in error!"];
                    [self performSelector:@selector(dismmiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5f];
                    self.password.enabled = NO;
                }
            }
        }
        - (void)dismmiss{
            [CFBlurHUD dismiss];
            self.password.enabled = YES;
        }

`
```

Answer (score 0):

Because  current textfiled is password: `if (textField == self.password) {`. But you set:

```
[self.username resignFirstResponder];
```

It 's not correct.
Try:

```
[self.username resignFirstResponder];
  [self.password resignFirstResponder];
```

or :

```
self.view.endEditting = true;
```

> use your UITextFieldDelegate methods specifically UITextFieldShouldBeginEditing and return NO and execute the code to show the popover instead. This way the keyboard is never shown to begin with

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 [self.view endEditing:YES]; 

  return NO;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply dismiss a keyboard from view, try the following:

```
self.view.endEditing = true;
```

> use your UITextFieldDelegate methods specifically UITextFieldShouldBeginEditing and return NO and execute the code to show the popover instead. This way the keyboard is never shown to begin with

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 [self.view endEditing:YES]; 

  return NO;
 }
```

Comment: if it is inside the scrollview , your answer will be work

Answer (score 0):

First step for dismiss keyboard Give textfeild delegate in storyboard

[image: Select textFeild drag into view controller]

[image: Give textFeild delegate]

Or Also give by code :

```
self.txtName.delegate = self;
```

Dismiss keyboard when tap gesture method called:

```
- (void)dismmiss{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [CFBlurHUD dismiss];
    self.password.enabled = YES;
}
```

or Also Dismiss when touch anywhere in View:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Or when user press return button in keyboard:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```